# XNU Kernel clone in DCPU-16

Tags: assembly, kernel, bsd, dcpu-16, mach

https://github.com/galaxas0/MachX-Kernel

Before I embark on a project designed to fail, I'd like to set things straight so they don't fail, by asking a simple question: how on earth would a DCPU-16 load a kernel... being virtual and all. I understand the process of bootstrapping and kernel init on a physical computer, however, the DCPU-16 has me at a loss. Should I assume it is indeed a 1:1 16-bit processor that works the exact same way?

Answer (score 1):

The DCPU-16 is just a CPU core with memory. There are I/O extensions, but I don't think any of them makes it very straight-forward to bootstrap the CPU. Most emulators just pre-load the emulated processor's memory with whatever data you want to have there, before starting the CPU.

It's certainly nowhere near the state of the art, but my [very own DCPU-16 emulator](https://github.com/unwind/cade/blob/master/cade.h) certainly behaves that way, too.